# Bad performance with ATI Radeon X1300?

Tags: 10.04, video, performance, ati

i'm having problem with Ubuntu 10.04 and my Ati radeon X1300. 
In particular i can't enable effect (compiz) because they are SLOW, and, for example, the same game (hedgewars) on the same pc run very slowly on Linux, nor in Windows.

With my old Ubuntu (9.04) i didn't have the same problem.

Does anyone help me to "configure" the right driver for my video card ? I've tested with proprietary (fglrx) and open (xorg..-ati-radeon)... Either give me some problem :(!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the open source or restricted driver? Try going to the hardware drivers and disabling the proprietary one if it is enabled. For some situations the open source one is better.

Comment: Actualli i've tested with proprietary (fglrx) and open (xorg..-ati-radeon)... Either give me some problem :(!

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have *ATI Radeon 9600m* and works very well with "**r300g**" driver. To install you only need to add xorg-edger PPA.

Open terminal and copy&past `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and press enter. After copy&paste `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade` and press enter.

You can check which driver do you use by command `glxinfo` (Install: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`). Check line `OpenGL renderer string`. It should contain `r300g`. If you have `software rasterizer` its not OK.

Comment: Looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver indicates that the r300g is probably a good choice for the X1300 card.   (I had similar problems with an X1250, which of course likes the r600g driver.... go figure.)

Answer (score 1):

Another  solution (a kind of voodoo solution ), using the **open source drivers** is to run the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf
```

and to this blank file add the following

```
options radeon modeset=0
```

Save, Exit , Reboot and your problem will be probably solved

source: http://niccolofavari.com/ubuntu-10.04-lucid-issues-with-external-monitor-and-ati-radeon-card

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with radeon x1500 and x1600 so I supose the solution will be the same, and you must be using de mesa driver (the open source). I don't know if it works with the propietary fglrx (didn't for me...)

Reboot, and in the grub screen where you select the OS, pres "e" over the first entry. You will acces to a manual editor for the boot command.

Go to the end of the line with the linux kernel parameters. At the end it must be something similar like "ro quiet splash" (depending on your boot settings). After the last word, and with a space between, tipe "pci=nomsi" (without the "") DON'T PRESS INTRO, because all the orders must be in the same line... if there's no space when you write the last part, it will appear down but it's considered all the same line.

Pres control+x and you'll bot with the new parameter. Try activating compiz, running some games in 3D etc... If it doesn't work don't worry, you didn't change anything and the next time you boot the parameters will be the originals.

The problem is everytime you reboot you have tu do that, so if it worked you can make it permanent installing Grub Customizer:

sudo aptitude install grub-customizer

Open it from apps, system utilities, go to preferences, general, and in the kernel parameter box put "pci=nomsi" (again, without the ""). Close, save the new parameters and reboot.

If there's any problem, just run the program again and delete the new parameter.

I wish it helps. Good luck!